# TypeError parsing JSON obj from urllib ipython

Tags: python, ipython, urllib

I am using an API to request data from a website. The data can be found [here](http://maplight.org/services_open_api/map.bill_list_v1.json?apikey=79bf8eb2ded72751cc7cda5fc625a7a7&jurisdiction=us&session=110&include_organizations=1&has_organizations=1) and pasted into a [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). My code along with the error that it is returning are below. I am guessing that this is a quick fix, partially reflecting the fact that this is my first time using urllib.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib 
import json

api_key = '79bf8eb2ded72751cc7cda5fc625a7a7'
url = 'http://maplight.org/services_open_api/map.bill_list_v1.json?apikey=79bf8eb2ded72751cc7cda5fc625a7a7&jurisdiction=us&session=110&include_organizations=1&has_organizations=1'

json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-85ab9af07320> in <module>()
      8 json_obj = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
      9 
---> 10 data = json.load(json_obj)

/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    266         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    267         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 268         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    269 
    270 

/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    310     if not isinstance(s, str):
    311         raise TypeError('the JSON object must be str, not {!r}'.format(
--> 312                             s.__class__.__name__))
    313     if s.startswith(u'\ufeff'):
    314         raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Any suggestions, comments, or further questions are appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it wants `str`, not `bytes`.  Did you try `json.load(json_obj.decode('utf-8'))`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I just tried your suggestion. I received the following error `AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: Oops... `json.loads(json_obj.read().decode('utf-8'))` maybe?

Comment: I just noticed that ^. I tried both and received a corresponding error `AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Did you notice the `.read()` in my second suggestion?  IIRC, the `HTTPResponse` objects are file-like which means that to get the bytes data from them, you can call `.read()`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! That seems to have done the trick :)

Comment: With requests it is a simple `requests.get(url).json()`

Comment: Also if you are trying to put this into a df you can do it all with pandas

Comment: @ Padraic: I just tried the `requests.get(url).json()` and got the following error: `---> 12 requests.get(url).json()

NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.load` won't guess the encoding, so you typically need to `.read` the bytes from the object returned and then convert those bytes into a string by using `.decode` and the appropriate codec.  e.g.:

```
data = json.loads(json_obj.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

There is an example of this in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples).

Specifically, it says:

> Note that urlopen returns a bytes object. This is because there is no way for urlopen to automatically determine the encoding of the byte stream it receives from the http server. In general, a program will decode the returned bytes object to string once it determines or guesses the appropriate encoding.